# can some one please tell me Microsoft link where i can get IE 9 setup to install?

Tags: internet-explorer

I agree google helps but i would like to few additional thinks

1. Its not released yet right ?
2. If its not yet released where can i get it download ?
3. What all effects/sideeffects i can get using that ?

Please provide me Microsoft link from where i can download and install the IE 9 so i can play with HTML 5 and new stuff shipped with it.
Thanks all

Comment: Really? You couldn't be bothered to type "IE9" into the Google search box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the link Yin Zhu posted to the [IE9 Preview page](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/), and click the green "Install the preview!" button in the middle of the page.

IE9 hasn't been formally released yet, this is a platform preview, which includes a very basic user interface. This is not a beta version, that will come later. Microsoft just wants feedback on Trident (IE's rendering engine) at this stage, which is why they're releasing this platform preview.

Answer (score 1):

[IE 9 Preview](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/).

Comment: What all i found here is demoes, does it also have "IE 9 Download" link somewere ? sorry but i failed to find Mozilla or MicroSoft like download like BIG GREEN DOWN ARROW. Help with that will help, thanks